# What does Firefox AppArmor restrict/allow?

Tags: firefox, apparmor

I know the AppArmor profiles resides in `/etc/apparmor.d/`, but I do not know how to interpret it. Any translation would be enlightening.

Comment: You mean the configuration from `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox`? It looks very explanatory.

Comment: @Lekensteyn, no I do not know how to read it. And sorry about the new question, I posted it mistakenly after *I couldn't find my own question*.

Comment: It would be better if you had studied the syntax and then asked some more specific questions. There's plenty of documentation online. You can't expect anyone to explain the profile line by line. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor

Comment: @arrange, I was hoping someone would. :) You can't expect every user to learn to effects when considering using it.

Comment: @Oxwivi: I get your point, but right now there are 618 lines in FF-related apparmor profile files...

Comment: @arrange, isn't the only file the one @Lekensteyn mentioned? It only has 139 lines including commented ones. Regardless, lack of documentation suck.

Comment: @Oxwivi: no, because you have to include the files mentioned in the "#include" lines. This all is nicely explained in documentation which is IMO plentiful on the net. I will provide a sample link here again for your convenience: wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor

Comment: @arrange, I meant documentation of the profiles - that is how it's supposed to protect us and what might we expect not to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing confusing in there are the codes and your interpret them like this:

```
'r'  read
'w'  write
'm'  memory map as executable
'k'  file locking
'l'  creation hard links
'ix' execute and inherit this profile
'Px' execute under another profile, after cleaning the environment
'Ux' execute unconfined, after cleaning the environment
```

The rest of the file are mainly directories, files and libraries with sometimes some parameters in front (like PROC and HOME which seem easy to understand) and regexes to make it more flexible and sometimes a 'deny' or 'owner' in front of the line (these seem to be self-explanatory to me: they deny access and limit actions in case it is the owner doing them).

Regarding PROC:

Example:

```
# for networking
  network inet stream,
  network inet6 stream,
  @{PROC}/[0-9]*/net/if_inet6 r,
  @{PROC}/[0-9]*/net/ipv6_route r,
```

and do

```
cd /proc/
ls *
```

See all the directories with digits? These correspond to each running process.
If any of them contain a directory `net` (`network`) and that holds a file `if_net6` or `ipv6_route` they are considered `read`.

Comment: HOME I understand, but not PROC.

Comment: Also there are some lines without any of the parameters defined.

Comment: so the code behind it says what permission it gets systemwide for every user.

Answer (score 2):

See `Access Modes`, `Rule Qualifiers`, and  `#include mechanism` in the man page...

```
man apparmor.d
```

The man page explains it pretty verbosely.  Regarding your question about `@{PROC}` there are variables which can be set within include files.  From the apparmor.d(5) man page...

> Some of the abstractions rely on variables that are set in files in
>   the `/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/` directory. These variables are currently
>   `@{HOME}` and `@{HOMEDIRS}`. Variables cannot be set in profile scope;
>   they can only be set before the profile. Therefore, any profiles that
>   use abstractions should either `#include <tunables/global>` or otherwise
>   ensure that `@{HOME}` and `@{HOMEDIRS}` are set before starting the
>   profile definition. The `aa-autodep(8)` and `aa-genprof(8)` utilities will
>   automatically emit `#include <tunables/global>` in generated profiles.

If you look in `/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/global` you'll see there's another `#include <tunables/proc>`.  The contents of that file is....

```
# Copyright (C) 2006 Novell/SUSE... GNU GPLv2... more license info...
# @{PROC} is the location where procfs is mounted.
@{PROC}=/proc/
```

So `@{PROC}` is simply an abstract variable pointing to the [proc(5) filesystem](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt?id=refs/tags/v3.15-rc2).